# System Settings icons missing

Tags: upgrade, 13.10, system-settings

Is there any way to reset the System Settings Control Panel page?

The Control Panel was fine, but the for no apparent reason, PRIVACY, BACKGROUND and a host of other icons have vanished...

My system seems pretty messed up after the upgrade... Shutdown, Reset, and Logout from the menu no longer work either...

[image: Settings with, presumably, icons missing]

However, I can launch the Privacy panel from the terminal:

```
activity-log-manager
```

and it runs... so why is this, and others, now missing from the System Setting Control Panel?

I have checked and: **activity-log-manager-control-center** is installed

Is there a config file I can check, or a setting in Gconf where the list of icons are referenced?

I have run - in desperation -

```
sudo apt-get purge unity*
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Run Gconf-cleaner and Janitor

then re-installed all packages

Still the same issue....?

Comment: Related, though not necessarily a duplicate (different icons missing): [System Settings icons missing in 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/466720/22949)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution. In the end I backed up and did a fresh install. All working fine after that.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but in case this happens again try running:

> sudo apt-get install unity-control-center

it worked for me when I ran into a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Xubuntu. I restored the icons in the settings manager by editing the `.desktop` files in `~.local/share/applications/` and changing

```
Hidden=true
```

to

```
Hidden=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me with the same issue. Run `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal. In my case, this did not successfully complete but it did recommend to run `dpkg` and specified the exact commandline command to run.

This appeared (a best guess) to complete some of the steps that may not have been properly completed within the upgrade process itself. After this there were no missing icons and everything appears to be as expected. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have the same problem. Your suggestion did not apply to my system.