# System Settings icons missing in 14.04

Tags: unity, icons, settings, system-settings

I did a fresh install of trusty 14.04, but a lot of icons are missing.
I installed from DVD which was painfully slow and I hope to avoid repeating the process, especially since I started customizing stuff.

Here's my settings window:

[image: System Settings]

I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-settings-daemon-schemas
```

None of which changed anything.

Any idea? I wanna edit preferences and none of them are in System Settings, neither in Unity Dash.

Comment: Try installing `unity-control-center`.

Comment: this worked for me: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: got same problem removing evolution-data-server. Lesson: don't do it ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing System Settings after removing some packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453440/missing-system-settings-after-removing-some-packages)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem - same icons missing as well. I had stupidly uninstalled `gnome-bluetooth`, and nothing was fixing it. So I did what user282306 (r00t) suggested -

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

And I've got them all back again.

Kudos @user282306 (previously r00t) for [the suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466720/system-settings-icons-missing-in-14-04/468235#comment618315_466720).

Comment: I don't understand why in the hell there are not this settings apps by default...

Comment: @logoff there are. This would happen after a bad install or removing a package that you shouldn't - basically anything that starts with `gnome-`, for example `gnome-bluetooth`.

Comment: @Tim so strange, I did a fresh install on a VM adding a few new packages, not removing.

Comment: Was one of those `gdm` or part of a GNOME shell?

Comment: Thanx a lot....

Comment: That's overkill for what is needed. `unity-control-center` is all that is needed.

Comment: @K I obviously can't test that, but why not post as an answer?

Answer (score 13):

This issue was resolved for me by (re-)installing `unity-control-center`

`apt-get install unity-control-center`.

I didn't want to re-install the whole `ubuntu-desktop` because it was going to install a bunch of packages I didn't want/need and use another 100MB of space.

Compared to just 4MB with `unity-control-center`

Comment: Very effective solution. Had the same problem and the above solved it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Most likely (probably due to some dependency issue) below packages were removed:

- unity-control-center-signon
- gnome-control-center-unity

This command should resolve this issue:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center-signon gnome-control-center-unity
```

Comment: This has to be the most annoying problem out there. Thanks. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Awesome WM, to start the settings panel, use either of:

- (17.04+)

  ```
  XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity7 unity-control-center
  ```
- (16.10-)

  ```
  XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity unity-control-center
  ```

See [unity-control-center icons missing when using xsession desktop with awesome window manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868795/unity-control-center-icons-missing-when-using-xsession-desktop-with-awesome-wind)

Comment: Yep, this fixed it for me on Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity 7.5.

Comment: Still works on Ubuntu 20.04.