# Sound settings missing

Tags: system-settings, indicator-sound

When I click on the sound icon then sound settings Systems Settings opens and there is no sound setting menu.  In fact the only icons in the System Settings window, there are 4 icons:  Language Support, Security and Privacy, Landscape Service and Software and Updates.  What happened to all of the other settings icons?  Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit  GB

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/466720/system-settings-icons-missing-in-14-04/468235#468235

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing System Settings after removing some packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453440/missing-system-settings-after-removing-some-packages)

Answer (score 1):

By adding Unity desktop and Alsa Mixer I was able to recapture the full System Settings and get the System Sound situation resolved.