# Problem with panel of configuration can't see more icons for settings dialogs?

Tags: 14.04, configuration

Here the image I can't see the  buttons

[image]

I was using my Ubuntu and now I cant see all menus of configuration Ubuntu panel.. Please I need help !!

Ubuntu 14.04 Unity LTS

Comment: @Eliah Customised unity I believe. OP: What tutorial did you use to make it look like OS X?

Comment: Sorry I cant speak english well because I speak spanish and sure I  wrote  wrong ... and

@EliahKagan yes my problem is that Is it that there should be more more icons for settings ...and I use Ubuntu 14.04 Unity...

Comment: And @Tim here the link to mac theme and others ..   http://kb.openstudioproject.com/content/ubuntu/best-ubuntu-1404-trusty-themes
And install ubuntu tweek to use some theme and to combinate icons Numix !!

Comment: Based on the expanded problem description, that you're running Unity, and the specific icons that are shown/missing, I think this is the same problem as in [System Settings icons missing in 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/466720/22949). Does running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, as suggested in [r00t's answer-turned-comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/466720/system-settings-icons-missing-in-14-04#comment618315_466720) and [Tim's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/468235/22949) there, fix this for you? (You might want to run `sudo apt-get update` first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that running this command was necessary for making the icons appear in System Settings:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```