# System settings path

Tags: icons

I deleted the icon of system settings.
Where can I find system settings application (in which directory), so I could restore its shortcut?
Thanks

Comment: Checked in the recycle bin and its not there ?

Comment: Thanks for fast respone. No, recycle bin is empty, im not sure how icon disappeared.  In location  /usr/bin/ there is no one of decribed files. I installed gnome-control-center  and run it, but instad of all icons thera are only four. (printers, languages, landscape service and upgrade).

Comment: I found soultion: http://askubuntu.com/questions/466720/system-settings-icons-missing-in-14-04?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The system settings executable should be `/usr/bin/unity-control-center` or `/usr/bin/gnome-control-center`