# unity-control-center icons missing when using xsession desktop with awesome window manager

Tags: unity, .desktop, awesome, unity-control-center

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 on amd64.  I'm using `xsession` ("User Defined Session") as my desktop, so that everything is started from my `~/.xsession` script.  This script starts the `awesome` window manager and various other programs, including `unity-settings-daemon`.

I would like to use the `unity-control-center` ("System Settings") application to set various settings.  Under 16.04 this worked fine.  After upgrading to 16.10, most of the icons are missing from the control center.

It seems that this is due to the fact that the files in `/usr/share/applications/unity-*-panel.desktop` have the line `OnlyShowIn=Unity;`.  If I comment out this line from, say, `/usr/share/applications/unity-datetime-panel.desktop`, then the "Date and Time" icon appears when I run `unity-control-center`.  But this is not a very good solution since, as far as I can tell, it will be reverted whenever the `unity-control-center` package is upgraded.

Is there a better way to be able to use all the control center panels in my setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html, the `OnlyShowIn` key is matched against the value of the `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` environment variable.  So we can trick `unity-control-center` into showing all the panels by running

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity unity-control-center
```

This seems to work fine.

Under Ubuntu 17.04 and above, `Unity` should be changed to `Unity7`.