# In Ubuntu 16.04 clock missing in System Settings

Tags: unity, system-settings, clock

Clock is missing from System Settings in Ubuntu 16.04:

[image]

Comment: Yes, the helps are on https://askubuntu.com/questions/868795/unity-control-center-icons-missing-when-using-xsession-desktop-with-awesome-wind https://askubuntu.com/questions/466720/system-settings-icons-missing-in-14-04?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/251070/appearance-icon-has-disappeared-from-system-settings-menu

Comment: Thank you Sadaharu Wakisaka, this command *sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop* workes.